Problems with Frege's theory regarding anaphorisms and indexicals
While reading Propositoinal Attitude Reports, I came across a part I don't understand.

Consider the following.
(8) Jack and Jill went up the hill and Jack believes that she went up first.
There is a reading of (8) where ‘she’, as it occurs in (8), is anaphoric on ‘Jill’; that is, ‘she’ is anchored to ‘Jill’, in the sense that the reference of the former is inherited from the reference of the later. ‘Jill’, as it occurs in (8), is outside the scope of a propositional attitude verb and hence has its customary reference. So, then, it would seem, ‘she’ must also have the customary reference of ‘Jill’ and hence must refer to an individual and not a sense. This runs contrary to Frege’s reference-shift claim.
(...)
The Fregean should not be terribly perturbed by these observations. (...) In his 1969, Kaplan taught us how we can be Fregeans and allow quantifying into attitude verbs. (...) A sentence like (8) would then be read as something like: “Jack and Jill went up the hill and (there is an individual-concept c that ”designates“ Jill such that) Jack stands in the belief relation to the proposition consisting of c and the semantic value of ‘went up first’.”

In the above paragraph it is claimed that Kaplan's theory can maintain Fregeanism while dealing with anaphorisms inside belief contexts. But the subsequent paragraph goes on like this.

The simple Fregean solution, however, faces other, more serious, problems. First, the account seems to fail when we try to extend it to other types of attitude reporting sentences than the classical examples we have considered above. One of our most common ways of referring to individuals is to use indexicals and demonstratives, such as ‘I’, ‘you’, ‘this’, ‘she’, and ‘they’. (...) Consider, for example, the following sentence.
(10) Alice believes that I will solve an important problem in physics.
Suppose that Bob Smith utters (10). Smith’s use of ‘I’ tells us nothing about how Alice represents Smith; in particular, it does not refer to or otherwise involve anything that we would ordinarily call the sense of ‘I’. (...) Call this the problem of indexicals.

I don't understand why (8) and (10) are distinct problems. As to me, it seems that (10) could be explained the same way as (8), for (10) could be written out as (10'):

(10') I am Smith, and Alice believes that I will solve an important problem in physics.

and since the "I" in "Alice believes that I..." is now anaphoric on "Smith", it can be dealt with Kaplan's theory. So why does SEP consider (8) to be "not terribly perturbing" while (10) to be "more serious problem"?

Fregean semantics struggles with both because within the belief context reference shifts where names or terms inside belief contexts should not directly refer to their customary reference but to their senses as the mode of presentation. Kaplan's solution allows Fregeans to account for anaphora like ‘she’ referring back to ‘Jill’ even within belief contexts, by interpreting ‘she’ as an individual concept linked to Jill's sense. But in (10), ‘I’ is not anaphoric but an indexical whose reference shifts depending on who utters the sentence. Ayer pointed out similar ostensive indexical problems...

Because (8) contains a non-indexical name outside of attitudinal context to which the indexical "she" is anchored, while (10) contains no such non-indexical anchor for "I". Even adding "I am Smith" does not fix the problem because it is inside attitudinal context and only tells us about Smith’s use of "I", not Alice's. Hence "Smith’s use of ‘I’ tells us nothing about how Alice represents Smith". And however she does, it does not refer to anything like the usual sense of "I" when it is used directly. So Fregean reference shift to the sense is not what happens here.

@Conifold Why is it problematic that "Smith's use of 'I' tell us nothing about how Alice represents Smith"? Why can't I simply paraphrase (10) as "There is an individual-concept c that ”designates“ Smith such that Alice stands in the belief relation to the proposition consisting of c and the semantic value of ‘will solve an important problem in physics’?

You could also view the subtle difference here using rigid designator vs definite description since the propositional attitude report about any intensional belief content is necessarily within the modal scope of the said belief content. Therefore the proper name "Jill" is really a rigid designator across all possible worlds thus fully substitutable with "she" in this scope, while "I" even described definitely as the common name "Smith" in the actual world, it's not rigid thus unsubstitutable after any believe scope, posing a much more serious problem for the Freagean reference shift reading...

Because the "individual-concept c" (Smith) is not the sense of "I" when inside Alice's attitude, i.e. your paraphrase does not perform the reference shift that Frege's theory prescribes.

@Conifold I think my problem is that I can't understand why we can't just add a rule saying that, when A utters "B believes P('I')" (where P is a predicate), what is really said is "B belives P(A)" — like how Russell claimed that what definite descriptions really refer to is a higher-order predicate.

This might work if the attitudinal contexts were nested, i.e. if Smith was reporting on what he believes that Alice believes. But he plainly reports what Alice believes while the reference of "I" shifts as if the contexts were nested. No simple reference shifting rule can accommodate such behavior. Perhaps Fregeans could argue that the distinction between nested and concurrent contexts is shaky in speaker's minds and the shifts are blended opportunistically, i.e. write this off as pragmatics. But opponents contend that rigidity/innocence is a principled, and hence better, explanation.

@Conifold Sorry for keep asking you, but despite my best efforts it's not clicking for me. Could you be so kind as to explain what are the differences among the following sentences?
(1) A walked with B, and B thinks that A is happy.
(2) A walked with B, and B thinks that he is happy. ['he' is anaphoric on A]
(3) I walked with B, and B thinks that A is happy. [uttered by A]
(4) I walked with B, and B thinks that I am happy. [uttered by A]
